# Pointcut for overloaded methods

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspect, pointcut

If we have overloaded methods with nested calls as below

```
public void sample(int a) {
    sample(a, 5);
}

public void sample(int a, int offset) {
    System.out.println(a + offset);
}
```

There is a pointcut and advice as below

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * sample*(..))")
public void sampleMethod() {}


@Around("sampleMethod()")
public Object storeMetrics(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Advice called");
    }
```

Now, if sample(10) is called, I get "Advice called" twice as the output. Does this mean poincut intercepts both the overloaded the methods?

But consider the case where the method is not overloaded as below. Now it prints "Advice called" only once even both the methods match the pointcut expression

```
public void sample(int a) {
    sampleWithOffset(a, 5);
}

public void sampleWithOffset(int a, int offset) {
    System.out.println(a + offset);
}

@Pointcut("execution(public * sample*(..))")
public void sampleMethod() {}


@Around("sampleMethod()")
public Object storeMetrics(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Advice called");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `@Around` aspect does not compile because it does not return a result. You maybe forgot to copy something like `return jp.proceed();` from your code.

> Now, if sample(10) is called, I get "Advice called" twice as the output. Does this mean poincut intercepts both the overloaded the methods?

Of course, because your pointcut matches both method names. If you want different behaviour, change your pointcut.

> But consider the case where the method is not overloaded as below. Now it prints "Advice called" only once even both the methods match the pointcut expression

Your statement is false. The aspect also prints twice. Here is proof:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public void sample(int a) {
    sample(a, 5);
    sampleWithOffset(a, 9);
  }

  public void sample(int a, int offset) {
    System.out.println(a + offset);
  }

  public void sampleWithOffset(int a, int offset) {
    System.out.println(a + offset);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().sample(11);
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(public * sample*(..))")
  public void sampleMethod() {}

  @Around("sampleMethod()")
  public Object storeMetrics(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(jp);
    return jp.proceed();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.sample(int))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.sample(int, int))
16
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.sampleWithOffset(int, int))
20
```